# Professor Title in Application?

Tags: graduate-admissions

On my grad school applications for an American Statistics MS, the application asks for the Professor title. I've always referred to my professors with the "Professor" title, but I'm wondering if title on a grad school application is concerning their official position / ranking in the department?

For example, one of my professors has a PhD from my Alma Mater but on the department website, it indicates she is a Lecturer. Should I indicate she is a Lecturer on the application? Or is it still appropriate to list her as a Professor?

Another one is indicated as "Professor & Graduate Vice Chair". Is it relevant to include the Graduate Vice Chair part or should I only include Professor?

Please point me in the right direction or provide some clarity if you can. I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand...does it just want the salutation (e.g., so the automated form that asks them to upload a letter will address them correctly)? Or does it want the person's academic rank? Or is that what you're asking (in this case, maybe describe what it says, or include a screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the official departmental website and use the official title. If the departmental website itself is inconsistent (sometimes happens), pick any designation.

Comment: Fortunately my department website has indicated the title of each professor in the department (Lecturer, Senior Lecturer, Distinguished Professor, etc.). My main worry would be diminishing the credentials of my letter writers by indicating that some are Lecturers, implying that they might not necessarily have a PhD and may be less qualified to assess my potential. However, I don't want to lie in my application.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem. First of all, most lecturers actually have PhDs. Also, they could always Google that person's name to find out.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, Professor is probably fine for any situation, since it can be interpreted as a position rather than the explicit title. Dr. works as well, assuming he/she has a doctorate. You don't need to be overly formal in the US, unlike some other countries. No one is likely to be offended by any academic title. Mr. and Ms. are probably less fine.

Comment: My main worry would be diminishing the credentials of my letter writers by indicating that some are Lecturers, implying that they might not necessarily have a PhD.